# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ix)^\alpha (i(x+y))^\alpha} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $k\neq 0$, $y\neq 0$ be real numbers and let $0<\alpha<1$.
Then, how can I evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ix)^\alpha (i(x+y))^\alpha} dx \; ?$$
Note that the integral converges as the improper Riemann integral. We interpret $(ix)^\alpha$ and $(i(x+y))^\alpha$ to be in the principal branch, where the argument is in $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Mathematica cannot evaluate this integral.

Comment: Note we also have singularities at $x=-y$ and $x=0$ [as far as Riemann improper integral is concerned].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume $y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. For $x<0$,
\begin{align*}
 (\mathrm{i}x)^\alpha &= (-\mathrm{i}u), \\ \left[ \mathrm{i}(x+y)\right]^\alpha  &= \left[ -\mathrm{i}(u-y)\right]^\alpha \text{for } u > y, \text{where } u\equiv -x \text{ (therefore } u \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\text{)}.
 \end{align*}

Now let

\begin{align*}
J &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ix)^\alpha (i(x+y))^\alpha} dx  \\
&= \int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-iku}}{(-iu)^\alpha \left[-i(u-y)\right]^\alpha} du + 
\int_{0}^{y}\frac{e^{-iku}}{(-iu)^\alpha \left[ i(y-u)\right]^\alpha} du +
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ix)^\alpha (i(x+y))^\alpha} dx\\ 
&= e^{i\pi\alpha}\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-iku}}{u^\alpha \left[(u-y)\right]^\alpha} du + 
\int_{0}^{y}\frac{e^{-iku}}{u^\alpha \left[ (y-u)\right]^\alpha} du + 
\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{(ix)^\alpha (i(x+y))^\alpha} dx\\ 
&= J_{1} + J_{2} + J_{3}
\end{align*}

For the evaluation of $J_{1}$, let $t\equiv (u-y)^{1-\alpha}$. Then we have

\begin{align*}
 J_{1} &= e^{i\pi\alpha}\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-iku}}{u^\alpha \left[(u-y)\right]^\alpha} du \\
 &= \gamma e^{i\pi\alpha}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ik(t^\gamma + y)}}{(t^\gamma + y)^\alpha} dt
\end{align*}

where $\gamma \equiv 1/(1-\alpha)$.

Mathematica gives $J_{1}$ as

\begin{align*}
J_{1} =\frac{y^{-2 \alpha } e^{i (\pi  \alpha -k y)}}{8 \sqrt{\pi } k} \left(i 4^{\alpha } k^2 y^2 \Gamma (1-\alpha ) \Gamma \left(\alpha -\frac{1}{2}\right) \\ \, _2F_3\left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha }{2};  \frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\alpha ,2-\alpha ;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)+\\4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (1-2 \alpha ) (k y)^{\alpha } \\ \left(e^{i \pi  \alpha } (k y)^{\alpha +1} \, _2F_3\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}+\frac{1}{2},\frac{\alpha }{2}+1;\frac{3}{2},\alpha +\frac{1}{2},\alpha +1;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)-\\4^{\alpha } \Gamma \left(\alpha +\frac{1}{2}\right) \sqrt{k y} \cos \left(\frac{k y}{2}\right) \left(J_{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha }\left(\frac{k y}{2}\right)+i e^{i \pi  \alpha } J_{\alpha -\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{k y}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)
\end{align*}

where $\, _pF_q(a;b;z)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.

For $k=y=1$,  $\lim_{\alpha \to 1/2} J_{1} \approx  1.62844 - 0.0939721i$ (same as GEdgar's).

Also, for $k=y=1,\alpha=1/2$, Mathematica gives

\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2} (i(x+1))^{1/2}} dx= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}  \left(G_{2,4}^{3,0}\left(\frac{1}{4}|
 \begin{array}{c}
  \frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4} \\
  0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \\
 \end{array}
 \right)+i G_{2,4}^{3,0}\left(\frac{1}{4}|
 \begin{array}{c}
  \frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4} \\
  0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
 \end{array}
 \right)\right)
\end{align*}

where $G$ is the MeijerG-function. This last function numerically evaluates as $J_1$ for for $k=y=1,  \alpha=1/2$.

Gradshteyn & Ryshik give the real and imaginary parts of $J_{2}$ as

\begin{align*}
Re[J_2] = \frac{1}{2} B(1-\alpha ,1-\alpha ) y^{1-2 \alpha } (\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;-i k y)+\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;i k y))
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
Im[J_2] = -\frac{1}{2} i B(1-\alpha ,1-\alpha ) y^{1-2 \alpha } (\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;i k y)-\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;-i k y))
\end{align*}

where $B(a,b)$ is the Euler beta function and $\, _1F_1(a;b;z)$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
 J_{2} = \frac{1}{2} B(1-\alpha ,1-\alpha ) y^{1-2 \alpha } (\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;i k y)-\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;-i k y))+\frac{1}{2} B(1-\alpha ,1-\alpha ) y^{1-2 \alpha } (\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;-i k y)+\, _1F_1(1-\alpha ;2-2 \alpha ;i k y))
\end{align*}

For $k=y=1, \alpha=1/2, J_{2} \approx  2.58737 + 1.41349i$ (the signal of the real part differs from GEdgar's $J_{2}$). In fact,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{0} \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2} (i(x+1))^{1/2}} dx=e^{-\frac{i}{2}} \pi  J_0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Finally, Mathematica gives $J_{3}$ as

\begin{align*}
J_{3} = \frac{\pi  e^{-i \pi  \alpha } y^{-2 \alpha }}{8 k \Gamma (\alpha ) \Gamma (2 \alpha )} \left(i \pi  4^{\alpha } k^2 y^2 \csc (2 \pi  \alpha ) \Gamma (2-\alpha ) \Gamma (2 \alpha ) \\ \, _2\tilde{F}_3\left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha }{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\alpha ,2-\alpha ;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)+2 k y \Gamma (\alpha ) (\csc (\pi  \alpha )-i \sec (\pi  \alpha )) (k y)^{2 \alpha } \, _2F_3\left(\frac{\alpha }{2}+\frac{1}{2},\frac{\alpha }{2}+1;\frac{3}{2},\alpha +\frac{1}{2},\alpha +1;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)+\\4 \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (2 \alpha ) (k y)^{\alpha +\frac{1}{2}} \cos \left(\frac{k y}{2}\right) \left(-2 \csc (2 \pi  \alpha ) J_{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha }\left(\frac{k y}{2}\right)+(\sec (\pi  \alpha )+i \csc (\pi  \alpha )) J_{\alpha -\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{k y}{2}\right)\right)\right)
\end{align*}

For $k=y=1$,  $\lim_{\alpha \to 1/2} J_{3} \approx  0.958926 - 1.31951i$ (same as GEdgar's $J_{3}$). For this particular choice of $k, y, \text{and } \alpha$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2} (i(x+1))^{1/2}} dx = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{i}{2}} \pi  H_0^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
where $H_0^{(1)}$ is the Hankel function of the first kind. This last function numerically evaluates as $J_3$ for $k=y=1,  \alpha=1/2$.

Summing up,

\begin{align*}
J = \frac{\pi ^{3/2} 2^{-2 \alpha -3} y^{-2 \alpha } e^{-i (\pi  \alpha +k y)}}{k \Gamma (\alpha )} \left(2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} i k y} \left(2 \csc (\pi  \alpha ) \sec (\pi  \alpha ) e^{i (\pi  \alpha +k y)} (k y)^{2 \alpha } \\ \left(\sqrt{\pi } k y \Gamma (\alpha +1) \cos \left(\frac{k y}{2}-2 \pi  \alpha \right) \, _2\tilde{F}_3\left(\frac{\alpha +1}{2},\frac{\alpha +2}{2};\frac{3}{2},\alpha +\frac{1}{2},\alpha +1;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)  \\ + 2 \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\alpha +\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{16} k^2 y^2\right) (\sin (2 \pi  \alpha )-\sin (k y-2 \pi  \alpha ))\right) \\+ 16^{\alpha } k y \csc (2 \pi  \alpha ) \left(-1+e^{i k y}\right) \left(e^{2 i \pi  \alpha } \left(1+2 e^{i k y}\right)+e^{i k y}\right) \, _0\tilde{F}_1\left(;\frac{3}{2}-\alpha ;-\frac{1}{16} k^2 y^2\right)\right)+i \sqrt{\pi } 16^{\alpha } k^2 y^2 \csc (2 \pi  \alpha ) \Gamma (2-\alpha ) \left(e^{i k y}-e^{2 i \pi  \alpha }\right) \, _2\tilde{F}_3\left(1-\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\alpha }{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\alpha ,2-\alpha ;-\frac{1}{4} k^2 y^2\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Plotting $J$ as a function of $\alpha$, with $k = y = 1$, yields,

[[image: <span class=]$J[\alpha]$ plot" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM2ka.png)

Answer (score 1):

I tried $k=y=1,\alpha=1/2$.
So far, Maple gave me
$$
J_1 = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2}(i(x+1))^{1/2}}
= -ie^{i/2} K_0(i/2) \approx 1.628441993 - i 0.09397211088
$$
and
$$
J_2 = \int_{-1}^0 \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2}(i(x+1))^{1/2}}
=-e^{-i/2} \pi J_0(1/2) \approx -2.587367762 + i 1.413485450
$$
But it evaluated
$$
J_3 = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{ix}}{(ix)^{1/2}(i(x+1))^{1/2}}
\approx 0.9589257685 - i 1.319513339
$$
only in terms of Meijer G.

I wonder if $J_3$ is also a Bessel funtion?

---

Other values of $\alpha$.  Maple does some of them
$$
\int_{-\infty }^{-1}\!{{{\rm e}^{ix}}{\frac {1}{\sqrt [4]{ix}}}{\frac 
{1}{\sqrt [4]{i+ix}}}}\,{\rm d}x={\frac {{{\rm e}^{{i/8}
 \left( \pi-4 \right) }}\Gamma \left( {3/4} \right) {{K}_{
{1/4}}\left({i/2}\right)}}{\sqrt {\pi}}}
\\
\int_{-\infty }^{-1}\!{{{\rm e}^{ix}} \left( ix \right) ^{-3/8} \left( i+ix \right) ^{-3/8}}\,{\rm d}x={\frac {{{\rm e}^
{i\pi{5/16}-{i/2}}}\Gamma \left( {5/8}
 \right) {{K}_{{1/8}}\left({i/2}\right)}}{\sqrt {
\pi}}}
$$
But Maple does not do others, such as $1/3$.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting answer! It is still interesting that $J_1, J_2$ are evaluated with special functions. WLOG we can assume $k=1$, and I think $\alpha=1/2$ is the most "non-trivial" assumption. Is the simple evaluation of $J_1, J_2$ valid for other $\alpha$'s?